# How to recursively sum-up the leaves node of a nested tree dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary, tree

As shown in the example below, I would like to recursively find the leaves nodes, then calculate the sum of those leaves node. If the sum is greater than some threshold, then delete those leaves node, otherwise ignore it and move on to the next set of leaves node.

```
tree= {'Age': {'> 55': 0.4, '< 18': {'Income': {'high': 0, 'low': 0.2}}, 
               '18-35': 0.25, '36-55': {'Marital_Status': {'single': {'Income': 
               {'high': 0, 'low': 0.1}}, 'married': 0.05}}}}
```

For example, first Income node has two leaves (0,0.2) with a sum of 0.2. I would like to delete these leaves nodes since sum is greater than the threshold
Another example, second income node has two leaves (0, 0.1) with a sum of 0.1, I would like to ignore it since sum is less than threshold

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have some nested dictionaries with a somewhat undefined structure, but at some depth these dictionary trees may contain `Income` keys, the value these keys is a dictionaries which has numbers as values an you want to find and sum all of those. In your example,  `'18-35': 0.25` would also be a leaf, but you are not interested in those.
Right?

In this case:

```
def recurse_through_tree(tree):
    for (key, value) in tree.items():
        if key == "Income":
            assert isinstance(value, dict)
            summed = sum(value.values())
            # handle your threshold condition. For debugging print("sum="+str(summed))
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            recurse_through_tree(value)
```

might get you started.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to sum those values and if the sum is greater than some threshold value, I would like to delete those two nodes and replace it with summed value. I am expecting resulting tree as, tree= {'Age': {'> 55': 0.4, '< 18': {'Income': 0.2}, 
               '18-35': 0.25, '36-55': {'Marital_Status': {'single': {'Income': 
               {'high': 0, 'low': 0.1}}, 'married': 0.05}}}}